# SurfaceSampling ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh, surface

I want to leverage ThreeJS's `SurfaceSampling` to add visual elements to the face of a 3d model object similar to how noise is added in [this example](https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/LYyaxbb) (ref [this article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2021/08/31/surface-sampling-in-three-js/)):

`const sampler = new THREE.MeshSurfaceSampler(torusKnot).build();`

———

When trying to apply this technique to [my example](https://codepen.io/nickbewley/pen/poGWbOz), though, I receive an error:

`this.geometry.getAttribute is not a function`

OR (depending on version):

`THREE.MeshSurfaceSampler: requires BufferGeometry triangle mesh`

the current code:

```
   var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
   loader.load( 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/40480/head.obj', function ( object ) {

      object.traverse( function ( child ) {
         if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            var scale = 8;
            $(child.geometry.vertices).each(function() {
               p_geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(this.x * scale, this.y * scale, this.z * scale));  
            })
            let sampler = new THREE.MeshSurfaceSampler( object.children[0] )
         }
      });

      Background.scene.add(p)
   });
```

———

How can I use ThreeJS's MeshSurfaceSampler (or other technique) to add visual elements to the face of a 3d model in [my example](https://codepen.io/nickbewley/pen/poGWbOz)?

Comment: Any specific reason, that you use r61, that outdated for a decade?

MeshSurfaceSampler requires a mesh of `BufferGeometry`.

Comment: Only because I'm a newbie with threejs @prisoner849, thanks for any of your ideas.